# CAS Policy error in ASP.NET web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, cas

I am using Devexpress controls in my WEb forms.I added the corresponding reference to my refrences folder while on adding the control (I am using grid here) gives me error

**This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.**

I checked the solutions

and changed my web config  as given in the link

However I get the same error
I am using VS 2010 and my .NET framework is 4 also I am running 32 bit OS XP

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I had this error earlier
I solved it by changing my **devenv.exe** config file which is located at

[C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE][1](If your Installation directory is C:)

What you need to do is add

```
     <runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
     </runtime>
```

Between your Configuration tags...By this you would be able to resolve your problem
But this gives rise to another problem...I had a dataset in another project which I could not inspect using Dataset Visualizer .The error I had was **could not load this custom viewer**.After hours of google search I found this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511798/show-visualizers-error-could-not-load-this-custom-viewer) and [Link2](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/NET/dll-on-the-network-will-that-be-a-problem/td-p/3435819/page/2)

Another solution I tried was changing to webconfig file .I added this configuration and it was working in run time although I still get this error in design time.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a little late, but you can add the following to your `web.config` and it should work:

```xml
<system.web>
  ...
  <trust legacyCasModel="true" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: This was needed in my case, in addtion the runtime section.  So I'm glad you added this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by allowing full control to users in security permissions of file after closing Visual Studio 2012. File name is devenv.exe.config in the following path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

Then open above file in notepad and add following line after `<runtime>` tag

`<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>`

save the file and start using Visual Studio 2012 with design view.
and now my error was gone.