# CAS Policy - Cannot open Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I migrated an project from VS2008 to VS2019 and now I'm getting this error:

> This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.

I cannot open any form designer, I checked the documentation but I really didn't understant, what I have to do?

I tried to create a new form, when I try to add an DevExpress component get the same error:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CAS Policy error in ASP.NET web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804383/cas-policy-error-in-asp-net-web-application)

Comment: You'd have to edit devenv.exe.config, that is *not* a great idea.  Leaving the framework target at 3.5 or editing the offending code is the better way.

Comment: This is not ASP.NET web Application, it is a Windows Form app, where is this devenv.exe.config file? I just kept framework target 3.5 but didn't work.

Comment: Located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\xxxx\Common7\IDE, where xxxx is the edition name (like Community).

Comment: Found it, but now when I set <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/> between runtime, my VS doesn't open, if I delete it, VS opens again

Comment: VS worked now, I inserted this policy in the bottom of the runtime, however my problem still remains, cannot open Forms Designer...

Comment: @FernandoDonizetiIto have you tried upgrading your version of the dev express libraries?

Comment: @DanielA.White I Installed the latest version of DevExpress, what else I need to do in my solution? How can I upgrade the dev express library? Or will it be automatically upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the DevExpress components, I didn't know, but there's an option to upgrade their version, Extensions > DevExpress > Project Converter, after that the forms designers opened again.