# VS2017: Could not load this custom viewer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to inspect a datatable created from an XML, using the magnifying lens both from hovering over the variable and from the Watch window. The error presented by VS2017 is "Could not load this custom viewer".

I've already tried:

1. the following [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511819/5048049)
2. I've checked and [this flag is not present[(https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513623/5048049)
3. verified hat lazy evaluators are turned off [see here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8280)
4. added a registry DWORD (32-bit) entry LoaderOptimization with value under omputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ .NETFramework and
   Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\ .NETFramework

Nothing is working. Any idea?

The version of VS is 15.2 26430.16

Comment: have you tried the "Tools->Import end export settings wizard -> Reset All Settings" option ?