# VS 2017 "Could not load this custom viewer"

Tags: debugging

I have a problem using VS 2017 15.3.3

I like to show a wpf window in the buildin debugger visualizer, and get the error above.

Things I tried:

- on another machine the visualizer shows up with same project
- a newly created wpf project also fails
- rebooted several times
- followed the advice here: [Stackoverflow "Show Visualizers Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511798/show-visualizers-error-could-not-load-this-custom-viewer), but did not get any information from the attached visual studio (no errors during visualizer start)

The visual studio environment was updated from VS 2015, and I had used the debugger visualizer "mole" from Shifflett/Smith in VS2015/VS2017, but deinstalled them now.

Next step may be reinstall of vs 2017 but I like to hear if there are any other things to check beforehand...